# what's android strategy when the device battery is low?

Tags: android, mdm, application-lifecycle

I would like to know what modules android "shutting down", and in which order, when the device battery is low.

I'm interested specially in case like this:
let's say my application is running, and in forground.  now I'm launching intent to start another app.  does low battery can prevent the other app from been launched?

also I'd like to know if I can control somehow what will be shout down first, and what should stay active until the device rich almost to 0%.

my application is non market, target to specific devices which been managed from MDM system, so if it's possible - it's legitimate to control kind of settings

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, stock Android doesn't implement a 'low battery killer'. Some vendor modifications do (HTC and possibly others), but there is no clear standard. They would typically shut down Blue tooth, GPS, WiFi and finally data and maybe dim the screen. If you are targeting specific devices, you should work with whoever produced the firmware for those to understand what exactly it does (if anything at all).

Comment: @Nikolay Elenkov: thanks. any idea if Samsung's stock Ice-Cream ROM for galaxy tab 10.1 (P5110) implement something which prevents apps from been launch on low battery state?